# Proving rearranged series for absolute convergence relative to the original

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Theorem:

T1. *If the terms of an absolutely convergent series be rearranged in any order, the new series will converge absolutely and to the same sum as the original series.*

How can this be independently proved for each $Z$, $R$ & $Q$? That are either positive, negative or positive and negative?

I'm currently trying to prove for a series of all terms that are positive.

if we take the series:

$a_1 + a_2 ... + a_n ... = s$ such that, $a_n$ > 0; let $s_n = a_1 + ... + a_n$

let $\sigma_n = a_{p_1} + ... + a_{p_n} $ be the rearranged series.

Although, how to proceed from here?

Comment: What do you mean by "How can this be independently proved for each ,  & ? "?

Comment: Note:  the stated question, in that duplicate only concerns absolute convergence, but the accepted answer shows that the limit can not change.